# When does there exist a point with a given ratio of distances to the vertices of a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, locus

I have the triangle `ABC` and an unknown point `P` not necessarily inside the triangle. Also, I have three lengths (`d1`, `d2`, `d3`) with the same ratio of lengths `PA`, `PB`, and `PC`. The question is does `P` exist?

$\frac{d1}{PA} = \frac{d2}{PB} = \frac{d3}{PC}$

I already know that the locus of points with fixed distance ratio from points `A` and `B` is a circle with centre laid on the extension of `AB` (or in one case a line). But, what is the constraint on the distance ratios of `P` with respect to `A`, `B`, and `C`, for `P` to exist?

Comment: You are basically asking when two Apollonian circles, corresponding to 
$$ \frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{d_1}{d_2},\qquad \frac{PA}{PC}=\frac{d_1}{d_3}$$
intersect.

Comment: Related: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TripolarCoordinates.html

Comment: Given p:q:r, the number of points having tripolar coordinates satisfying x:y:z=p:q:r depends on ap, bq and cr being the sides of a triangle (two points), a degenerate triangle (one point) or not a triangle (zero points) (Bottema 1987)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Yes, the question is basically when two of the Apollonian circles intersect. Maybe there is no simple formula for that.